# Remove each word in a string from a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I'm in a situation where I want to remove dynamically generated text from another piece of text..

```
  var string1 = "Hello, my name is irrelevant";
  var string2 = "Hello irrelevant, my name is blank";
```

So what I want is that when `string1` is "removed" from `string2` the result is `blank` because `string1` had all the same words as `string2` but even though they were in a different pattern they still get removed.

Is that possible? If I have a very large string would it be slow?

Comment: In my mind, I would probably approach this by solving this problem before the 2nd string is generated by managing it with a template, and comparing  the template to the string to remove what doesn't match the template.

Comment: I actually have no idea what you are asking. Can you give an example input/output?

Comment: @Jay If the input to `string1` is `"this is a string of words"` and `string2` is `"words of string"` then the output would be `"this is a"` because `string1` has some of the same words as `string2`... Does that make it more clear?

Comment: So all you are trying to do is remove the words that `string1` and `string2` have in common? Resulting basically in  `string1 xor string2`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generate a regular expression from `string1` and use that to eliminate words from `string2`:

```
var reg = new RegExp('\\b('+string1.match(/\w+/g).join('|')+')\\b','gi');
var unmatched_words = string2.replace(reg,'').match(/\w+/g);
alert(unmatched_words);
```

This should produce an array of every word that appears in `string2` but not in `string1`.

**EDIT:** As Guffa pointed out, the regular expression will also match partial words unless it is bookended with word boundary match strings (`\b`). I've updated the answer to include this change.

```js
var string1 = "Hello, my name is irrelevant";
var string2 = "Hello irrelevant, my name is blank";

var reg = new RegExp('\\b('+string1.match(/\w+/g).join('|')+')\\b','gi');
var unmatched_words = string2.replace(reg,'').match(/\w+/g);
alert(unmatched_words);
```

Comment: That will remove words that are part of other words, leaving the remaining characters. If you for example set the first string to `"Hello, my me is relevant"` it will return `["ir", "na", "blank"]`.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a map of the words from the first string, then loop through the words in the second string and check which ones are not in the map. Example:

```js
var string1 = "Hello, my name is irrelevant";
var string2 = "Hello irrelevant, my name is blank";

var map = {};

var words1 = string1.replace(/,/g, '').split(' ');
for (var i = 0; i < words1.length; i++) {
  map[words1[i]] = 1;
}

var result = [];
var words2 = string2.replace(/,/g, '').split(' ');
for (var i = 0; i < words2.length; i++) {
  if (!(words2[i] in map)) {
    result.push(words2[i]);
  }
}

document.write(JSON.stringify(result));
```

This will be an O(n) solution, i.e. the performance will be linear (or close to linear) to the length of the strings, so that will perform very well for large strings.

Comment: this is not a c# question